# Kendo UI Grid. Pager select list pops up out of screen and PageSize doesn`t work

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Pager doesn`t work as expected:

1. The option "Page Size" does not affect the grid.
2. "PageSize" selector appears out of the page borders

```
"pageable": {
    "pageSize": 10,
    "pageSizes": [5, 10, 20, 30, 1000],
    "buttonCount": 5,
    "refresh": true,
```

You can check full examle in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8jvz/3/)
And Here is the video with the second [problem described](http://youtu.be/jkq64P-hVwU)

Comment: Could anybody advise regarding the second problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pageSize` is a property of kendo datasource. Please remove it from the `pageable` option and set it to datasource.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { name: "Tea", category: "Beverages" },
    { name: "Coffee", category: "Beverages" },
    { name: "Ham", category: "Food" }
  ],
  page: 1,
  // a page of data contains two data items
  pageSize: 2
});
```

**Edit 1**

Page size docs http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-pageSize

**Edit 2**

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M8jvz/6/ it shows the pager buttons

[image]

**Edit 3**

here are the few changes i have made fix the issue

1. set the proper id for the schema
2. set the total for the data source in the schema

here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M8jvz/7/

Comment: Please check documentation http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-pageable.pageSize

Comment: I've tried to move "page Size" option to DataSource, but page doesn't work as expected still. I see 10 rows instead of all, but I don`t see the pager navigation buttons.

Comment: Please check the [link](www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUc5eInzOf8)

Comment: see my updated answer. the given fiddle has the pager working.

Comment: Thank you. But why the option pageable.pageSize doesn`t work as expected, why we should write such Crutches ?

Comment: i'm not sure but when you create a dataSource out side of the grid its is always good to put the pageSize inside the data Source and main reason for the broken pager is that the kendo dont know the total no of records available.

Comment: P.S. I found the answer in kendo.web.js  if (isPlainObject(dataSource)) {
extend(dataSource, { table: that.table, fields: that.columns });
pageable = options.pageable;
if (isPlainObject(pageable) && pageable.pageSize !== undefined) {
dataSource.pageSize = pageable.pageSize;
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Define `pageSize` in the `DataSource` definition:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    pageSize : 10,
    data     : l_json,
    schema   : {
        data : "row",
        model: {
            fields: {
                "DTRP_DT": {
                    type: "date"
```

See it here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/M8jvz/5/

Comment: It does not solve the problem, take a closer look at the result in jsfiddle. I don`t see navigation buttons in the pager.